# jQuery 'fade in' on page load without using 'display:none' in the css

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should hopefully be a simple one...

So I'm after a basic fade in on page load on my site, similar to what this site has... http://jack-hughes.com/

The problem I've got is that the standard jQuery fadeIn function seems to require 'display:none' on the element to be animated, which obviously means it stays hidden if someone has javascript disabled.

```
$('.h1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete
});
```

I could do with someone pointing me in the right direction as to get this effect without display:none on any of my elements.

I had a go myself to no avail. Simply attempted to check if the element existed, and if it did, set the css opacity to 0, then run the animation. I'm sure you can have a laugh at my expense (I'm not a JS guy). Thanks!

```
if($('.h1').length > 0) {
    $(this).css("opacity","0");
    $('.h1').animate({
        opacity:1,
    }, 1500, function() {
        //Animation Complete
    });
};
```

Comment: It's 2013. Anyone without JavaScript is either horribly behind the times or paranoid. Either way they shouldn't be surprised that most sites won't work for them. That said, is your animation really *necesary*?

Comment: I agree with you completely but I am curious as to how a workaround would be written. And no, the animation isn't necessary, but if everyone had that attitude then the web would be a boring place would it not?

Comment: There's a fine line between interesting and infuriating. I'm fairly sure people who have Flash-powered sites that take ten minutes to load think it's awesome, but they must scratch their heads at not getting any business.

Comment: Well this is for a design portfolio site so I think in this case it is appropriate. Animations can really improve the user experience if done in a tasteful and harmonious way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use display:none in your CSS and then include a simple style tag wrapped like so

```
<noscript>
    <style>
        #container { display:block !important; }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about hiding it first

```
$('.h1').hide().fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete
});
```

Comment: For me this causes a jump in the content as the element is hidden and then re-added to the page.

Comment: @Musa this works fine....my doubt is why to give headers or span ..to hide() before fadeIn()

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.h1').hide(<h1>hello</h1>).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete
});
```

write like this as per Musa